# Xaml Exporter for Blender

Tags: python

I am trying to get an old xaml exporter working in blender 2.79.

I have managed to get it showing up in the add-ons list but it when trying to enable it, i get a bunch of errors. I think the Blender API has changed because it won't import Blender. What can I do (not a python programmer)  Or if anyone knows of a Xaml Exporter thats working, let me know.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "XAML format (.xaml)",
    "author": "Daniel Lehenbauer and Robert Hogue",
    "version": (0, 0, 48),
    "blender": (2, 71, 0),
    "location": "File > Export > XAML",
    "description": "Export mesh to XAML",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=xamlexporter",
    "category": "Import-Export"}

from io import StringIO
from math import *

# ERROR HERE
import Blender
from Blender import Scene
from Blender import Texture
from Blender import Mathutils
from Blender import Lamp
import BPyMesh
import BPyObject
```

I have done some more work on it. The code is on [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/Sw8yMxge) I am getting the error shown in the image. [image]

Comment: The `import Blender` is an  indicator the addon is older than 2.5 (when `bpy` module was introduced)  Could update the addon, or install blender 2.49b 8*(

Comment: This one is obvious (old Blender version - Blender module was replaced by bpy module), but posting error messages will help indicating the problem in future. As for making this addon updated for current Blender version - surely doable, but there are many API changes since pre-2.5 version)

Comment: Okay, so I guess its a complete rewrite. I will think about if I want to do that (since I don't know python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3D in XAML is pretty much a dead since Microsoft dropped support for it.

I rewrote the script from scratch. You can the script from my [GitLab page](https://gitlab.com/AiRobotMedia/xaml-exporter-for-blender) which includes install and usage instructions as well as the license (MIT).

Comment: Excelllent. Could you give a quick run down on addon install and usage in answer? (Recall XAML was such a big thing in Vista, don't see it that much since I moved to ubuntu)

Comment: Link only answers are forbidden and your answer is in danger of getting removed. Please see the comment above and edit accordingly. Thanks! :) You can post the entire script here so if your gitlab account goes it might be helpful to someone else in the future.

Comment: Sorry, do you have a reference for your claim that Microsoft dropped support for it?